# How to use resValue in build.gradle?

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying [this](https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/keep-your-keys-outside-manifest-and-gradle-ba44110bafca) trick to keep the Sentry DSN and other keys out of the respository of my open source app (so everyone can add their own key via local.properties) but I'm failing already with the first step ("Move Manifest keys to Gradle").

Here's exactly what I did:

For debugging purposes I added this code to my `MainActivity.kt` to show me the current value:

```kotlin
val app: ApplicationInfo = this.getPackageManager()
    .getApplicationInfo(this.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)
val bundle = app.metaData
Toast.makeText(this, bundle.getString("foo"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

Then I replaced the value in `AndroidManifest.xml` with a string resource:

```xml
<manifest>
  <application>
    <meta-data android:name="foo" android:value="@string/manifest_foo" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

In `app/build.gradle` I added:

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        resValue "string", "manifest_foo", 'gradle_space'
        resValue("string", "manifest_foo", "gradle_parens")
    }
    ...
}
```

After this I got a build error `AAPT: error: resource string/manifest_foo not found.`.

So I added in `strings.xml`:

```xml
<string name="manifest_foo">from_strings_xml</string>
```

It builds and runs, but the value from `build.gradle` is not used:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: 1. You need to remove the entry from the strings.xml. In addition, You are setting the same resValue key with different value. gradle_space & gradle_parens. Is that intentional?

Comment: @gioravered If I remove it from strings.xml I get that build error. I wasn't sure which syntax is correct, with space after `resValue` or with parentheses. If any of them would work, I could remove the other.